# $user->id is there but won't save to a table in RegisterController | Laravel

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm having an issue with the Register Controller, when a user registers I want my Contacts table to create an entry for that user automatically. Everything works and when i do dd($user_id) I can see the id of the new user that just was made but it refuses to save it to the database. I am not sure why, the user_id has no problem in other instances like when a user makes a contact. Here is the Controller:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        $user->save();

        $user_id = $user->id;
        Contact::create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'fullName' => 'Me',
            // dd($user_id),
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The silliest thing, just figured it out after hours of trying to fix this. My Contact.php did not have user_id inside fillable!

```
   protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'fullName', 'email', 'phoneNumber'];
```

Comment: @kuldeep, you answered after the op figured the answer. Why should they upvote you?